# UILabel.text == self.NSString?

Tags: objective-c, if-statement, nsstring, uilabel

My question may be simple for some to answer, but I'm relatively new to Objective C and Xcode. So I have a UILabel and I am running an if statement asking if UILabel is equal to self.NSString then do ... Here is the code.

```
if (UILabel.text == self.NSString)
{
//Do Something here...
}
```

I'm wondering if this would work, or what I have to do in order for this to start working.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: UILabel and NSString are just illustrative names, you haven't named ivars like this, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `isEqualToString:` method from `NSString` class.

```
if([text isEqualToString:string])
{
  // Do something here.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When comparing strings, you should use

```
[UILabel.text isEqualToString:self.NSString]
```

The == simply compares the pointers, which will often be different even if their contents are the same. The isEqualToString method compares the contents.